# bash: atom: command not found how to resolve this in windows?

Tags: git, command

I am new at using this Git technology and started to learning some tutorials in youtube.

I am facing this problem but I can not avail it's solution.
And I do not know anything major about it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdMbL.jpg]

```
    $ atom .
bash: atom: command not found
```

---

> Can somebody please show me a right direction to solution??

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated by [atom/atom issue 11073](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11073), it is a PATH issue:

```
echo $PATH
```

In a regular CMD, type:

```
where atom
```

That will give you a `C:\path\to\atom`. (Make sure you had [Atom installed first](https://atom.io/))

In your bash session, you can add that path:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/c/path/to/atom
```

Then type "`atom`" in your bash session.

If this work, add that export line to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figure it out after doing these things.

First make sure you have atom installed in your computer.

After you need to check the path.

**Follow these steps for Windows 10:**

1. Open computer window and right click and click on Properties.
2. click on **Change setting**
3. Click on **Advanced**
4. Click on **Environment Variables**
5. [Two windows will pop 1. User  and 2. system variables]
   Go to **User** first and check path and click and **edit the path**. If it is not there Edit and add new path.
   In my case it is

   **C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/atom/bin**

[You need check in your pc where it is hidden]

6. click on ok
7. Same for the second window **System Variables**.
8. Check CMD as typing atom
9. So it will take you to atom

**Ultimately you will resolve the problem *command not found* after following these steps.**

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and reinstall the git setup. When installing, make sure to choose "use atom as text editor". You are cool to go

Comment: Sohan does not seem to be aware of the fact that atom is a text editor.  Maybe you should give him some details about why the error message is there in the first palce.